# kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'SmallPersistentVector' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization

I am trying to save an object, that contains a list using proto data store, but it cant serialize the object

I already added the `@Serializable` tag to the data class, how many sources suggest, but I still get this error, I cant make the class sealed, because I need to generate an object of it to pass to another class. Here is my code:
for my data class

```
@Serializable
@SerialName("SavedEvents")
data class SavedEvents(
    val SavedEventsList: PersistentList<Event> = persistentListOf()
)

@Serializable
@SerialName("Event")
data class Event(
    @Contextual
    val VEvent: VEvent
)
```

Method from Serializer:

```
override suspend fun writeTo(t: SavedEvents, output: OutputStream) {
        val json = Json {
            useArrayPolymorphism  = true
        }
        output.write(
            json.encodeToString(
                serializer = SavedEvents.serializer(),
                value = t
            ).encodeToByteArray()
        )
    }
```

And the exact error message:

```
 kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'SmallPersistentVector' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'PersistentList'.
    Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.
```